# EL content assist in Eclipse Indigo 3.7?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-wtp

I'm not able to use content assist (auto complete, etc.) for el in jsp files in eclipse indigo (wtp). I have create a new workspace and a new dynamic web project but no success.

Any idea how to enable it if possible at all (without installing myeclipse or jboss Tools)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure this isn't linked to [bug 307240](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=307240): Context Assistant for Expression Language does not work if no runtime is selected

[image: no content assist on EL]

> Steps to Reproduce:
>
> 1. Open eclipse
> 2. `File > New > Dynamic Web Project`
> 3. Fill in everything, **but do not select a target runtime**
> 4. `File > New > JSP file`
> 5. Type `${pageContext.` and hit CTRL-SPACE (mac)
>
> Actual result:
>
> You do not see any suggestions: No default Proposals

Comment: Thanks, I have added target runtime and now I'm able to get content assist after typing `${pageContext.|}`. But still unable to get it working for variable I define using `<jsp:useBean ...>` or `<%@attribute ...>`, there is a red message on status bar: Content Assist not available at current location. Any help is appreciated?

Comment: For example if I have `<%@ attribute name="aName" type="..." %>` and then typing `${aName.|}`.

Comment: @JohnS: sorry for the delay. I checked and don't have right now any new elements  on that lack of completion.

Comment: ok, thanks, so the problem is with my setup, I will try different configs and environments, maybe I can find a working setup.